# Unable to run command involving classes getter methods

Tags: c++, runtime-error

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzC5Z.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CnMd.png)

This is my main

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "players.hpp"

int main(){
    
    
    Players kev_dur("Kevin Durant", "Pheonix Suns", 35);
    cout << kev_dur.get_name();
}
```

** What does this error mean? Mentioning undefined symbols.

```
ld: Undefined symbols:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgI6k.png)
  Players::get_name(), referenced from:
      _main in main-85ce7f.o
  Players::Players(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, int), referenced from:
      _main in main-85ce7f.o
  Players::~Players(), referenced from:
      _main in main-85ce7f.o
      _main in main-85ce7f.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Created a Players class with constructor, and with getter methods. However, when trying to run `cout << kev_dur.get_name();` 
And throws that error out, nothing is wrong with my code, there's no miss spellings or any function errors.

I tried running it through bash and throughs the same error out. Retried closing VSCode but its not   that either.

Comment: Where are all the `Player` methods, such as `Player::get_name()`?  Please edit your post with plain text [mcve].

Comment: In the future it'll work much better if you upload your pictures and photos to Facebook or Twitter, instead. That's because those web sites are designed for that. Stackoverflow is designed for answerable questions that get asked ***in plain text***, so that everyone can cut/paste it and try it themselves. Can you remove all images and photos from your question, and include the same information as plain text, and verify that your question meets all requirements for a [mre], as explained in Stackoverflow's [help]? See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Do you have additional CPP files?  Did you specify them on the command line of the compiler or in the project of the IDE?

Comment: I tried to recreate your project, but my IDE doesn't accept images as source code.  Please edit your post with plain-text [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You need to include definitions for those missing functions. I suspect your header has something like

get_name();

But not

get_name(){ your code here }

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this answer?